# Facebook error 191 only on IE, possibly realssl

Tags: php, facebook

I'm currently developing an app, using PHP, and basically it's done, and while testing it, was not presenting any problem (Chrome), until tested on I.E. (7, 8 & 9)

The app can authenticate, but whenever i try to interact with the app, it shows the error

API Error Code: 191
 API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
 Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Esta URL no está permitida por la configuración de la aplicación.

Now, i've checked the application settings in fb, to be in correspondance with the redirect in PHP, simply don't see any problem:

(In Facebook)

URL del sitio
https :// secure3.realssl.com/pepitolapelicula/concurso/
Página de trabajo
https :// apps.facebook.com/concursospepito/
URL del lienzo
https :// secure3.realssl.com/pepitolapelicula/concurso/
Secure Canvas URL
https :// secure3.realssl.com/pepitolapelicula/concurso/
Lienzo FBML/iframe
iframe
Sandbox Mode
Activado
Deauthorize URL
https :// secure3.realssl.com/pepitolapelicula/concurso/

(In PHP the portion to auth)

```
$fbconfig['appid' ] = "000";
$fbconfig['secret'] = "000";

$fbconfig['baseUrl']    =   "https://secure3.realssl.com/pepitolapelicula/concurso/";
$fbconfig['appBaseUrl'] =   "http://apps.facebook.com/concursospepito/";


if (isset($_GET['code'])){
    header("Location: " . $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']);
    exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])){

}

$user  =   null; 
try{
    include_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));


$user       = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'publish_stream'));

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}

//get user basic description
$userInfo           = $facebook->api("/$user");
```

---

I think this might be something with the host provider (secure3.realssl), but honestly i don't have a clue right now. So, thanx in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is really strange, but...

I've managed to make things work using the example provided in this question (by SIR)
[authenticating facebook canvas application returns ?code=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642494/)

basically, the thing I noticed is that the code i used got the

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])){
    header("Location: " . $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']);
    exit;
}
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
```

While the example in SIR's answer first get's the $user, and after that checks for 'code'

Still, the strange thing is that only on IE the behavier was noted

Thanks